# Make a particular activity as a root activity in stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, android-intent

i have a set of activities on my stack Say A-->B-->C. when i launch
the activity named 'D' it should get fired as the root activity of my
application and all the other activities(A,B,C) should get cleared
from my stack once Activity D is launched.Can any one tell me as how
to do this

Answer (score 13):

Set root activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you go through this documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html, you can see the various intent flags and their uses.

Specifically, for your question, one has to use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** which will clear any existing task that would be associated with the activity before the activity is started i.e. the activity becomes the **new root** of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished.

Comment: **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** is not working by itself. You need to set it in conjunction with **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** (from Android documentation).